# AngularJS filter not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have AngularJS v1.2.19. I try use in my project

I have created filter for formation date.

```
var app = angular.module('commentApp', []).filter("dateformat", function ($filter) {
    return function (input) {
        if (input) {
            try {
                var date = $filter('CommentDate')(new Date(input), 'dd MMM yyyy');
                return date;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And call

```
<time>{{comment.CommentDate|dateformat }}</time>
```

I have got error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: CommentDateFilterProvider <-
>   CommentDateFilter
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$injector/unpr?p0=CommentDateFilterProvider%20%3C-%20CommentDateFilter

Comment: `$filter('CommentDate')` is asking angular to find another `.filter` that is named `CommentDate` and use `new Date(input), 'dd MMM yyyy'` as its input.  Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: why duplicate filters angular already has built in?

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once @charlietfl 's comment

Answer (score 0):

that means your filter `CommentDate` not exist

```
var date = $filter('CommentDate')(new Date(input), 'dd MMM yyyy');
```

you an use angular filter to format date https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

```
<time>{{comment.CommentDate|date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</time>
```

Comment: I try this filter. But this code don't work. Because I get json date /Date(1405349956890)/

Comment: I use array and array data I get from server use $http.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has Dependency Injection. It's not "magic" that it knows what things to pass into your function: it looks at the names of the parameters you accept, and tries to find things that match them. The way your code is written, Angular thinks you want it to go find a CommentDateFilter provider (and there isn't one).

Here's a simplified version with just the essentials:

```
var app = angular.module('commentApp', []).filter("dateformat", function() {
    return function(input) {
        return new Date(input).toLocaleFormat('dd MMM yyyy');
    }
});
```

I cheated here with toLocaleFormat() - that won't work in all browsers because it's new. I sensed that your question wasn't actually about formatting dates (because AngularJS has a very good date filter already: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date. I figured what you really wanted to know was how to get the actual filter working, and the example above will give you a starting point for building what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here: http://jsbin.com/taqiq/1/edit

that is code for your filter

```
app.filter('mydate' ,function($filter){

  return function(input){
    input =input.replace(/\//g, '');
    var mydate = Date.parse(Date(input));
    return $filter('date')(mydate, 'dd MMM yyyy');


  };

});
```